# How to achieve "white-space: pre;" in IE7?

Tags: css, whitespace

How to achieve "white-space: pre;" in IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 7 supports `white-space: pre;`.

Comment: IE 7 doesn't support `pre-wrap` as far as I can remember, unfortunately.